# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la orientación de un documento word usando python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

Acabo de descubrir esta librería y experimentando me ha surgido esta duda. La documentación da como ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT

section = document.sections[-1]
section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
```

El problema es que no sé como usarlo. Ni siquiera sé a qué se refiere con secciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las secciones son simplemente partes del documento que quieres que tengan un mismo formato.

Un mismo documento puede tener 1 o varias secciones, si por ejemplo quieres que tu portada sea en formato apaisado y el resto del documento en formato vertical deberás tener dos secciones.

Si lo que quieres hacer es cambiar la orientación debes tener en cuenta que tambien hay que cambiar las dimensiones, sería algo así.

```
new_width, new_height = section.page_height, section.page_width
section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
section.page_width = new_width
section.page_height = new_height
```

En la documentación viene mejor explicado como añadir nuevas secciones si lo deseas https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/sections.html